# Floating point comparison in Apple libraries

Tags: c++, ios, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I was checking CoreGraphics' CGGeometry.h the other days and bumped into this line for __CGSizeEqualToSize function:

return size1.width == size2.width && size1.height == size2.height;

both width and height are floating point numbers. Given that the use of epsilon for float comparison is claimed to be crucial in virtually every paper that has something to say about floating point numbers, how come one of the biggest software companies like apple go with this basic comparison in one of their most fundamental libraries?

Am I missing something?

Comment: What you are missing is that the rules change if you know what you are doing. For example, an iPhone 5 screen is 320 pixels wide. _Exactly_ 320 pixels. Not 319.999999 or 320.000001 but _exactly_ 320 pixels.

Comment: You are also missing that this method returns whether two sizes are _equal_. Not whether they are almost equal, but _exactly_ equal.